# How do you unlock the speed run mode?

Tags: not-golf

I've finally unlocked all 9 current courses, and gotten a negative score on each, ranging from -8 to -4. I have -54 total score.

The speed run mode icon still has a lock on it, and there's no in-game description of how to unlock it.

I don't even know what it is yet, but...how do you unlock speed run mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a perfect score on two courses in classic mode. 
This is indicated by the two greyed out stars on the speedrun "button"